# AWS beanstalk deployments wipe out environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, continuous-integration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an app that I am deploying through the AWS EB CLI.  When I initially setup the environment, I used `.ebextensions` files and ran `eb deploy` from the terminal on my machine.  This sets everything up correctly including environment variables and node version (8.9) in the beanstalk environment.

Now, if I deploy the app without the `.ebextensions` directory in the CI, the beanstalk environment gets spun up with default values which sets node back to v6.3 and wipes out the environment variables.

1) Is there a way to keep the current configuration of the beanstalk environment without having to deploy the `.ebextensions` files every time?

2) If I must deploy the `.ebextensions` files every time, what is the best approach for sensitive data like passwords?

---

Side note

I have another app in a different beanstalk environment that I deploy docker containers to.  In that instance, the beanstalk environment doesn't get nuked every time I deploy a new container update. I do not send the `.ebxtensions` files with this deployment either.